# How to upload a excel sheet from postman to Http Trigger Function

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-functions

I am trying to send an excel sheet from postman form-data body. How to get that file into http trigger function using java.

```
public class HttpTriggerFunction {
/**
 * This function listens at endpoint "/api/HttpExample". Two ways to invoke it using "curl" command in bash:
 * 1. curl -d "HTTP Body" {your host}/api/HttpExample
 * 2. curl "{your host}/api/HttpExample?name=HTTP%20Query"
 * @throws IOException 
 */
@FunctionName("creategroup")
public HttpResponseMessage run(
        @HttpTrigger(
            name = "req",
            methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
            authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
        HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        final ExecutionContext context) throws IOException {
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

    return null;
    

}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- I have created an HTTP Trigger Function in Java that accepts a file as input so that the function can listen the request (GET/POST) through the endpoint.

```java
@FunctionName("HttpTriggerJava")
public HttpResponseMessage run(

    @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
    HttpRequestMessage<Optional<FormDataMultiPart>> request,
    final ExecutionContext context) {
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

// Get the file from the form-data body_
    FormDataMultiPart  formData  = request.getBody().get();
    FormDataBodyPart  filePart  = formData.getField("file");
    InputStream  fileInputStream  = filePart.getValueAs(InputStream.class);

_// Process the file as needed_
_// ..._

    return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("The file which you have sent has been recieved.").build();
}
```

- The `getBody()` method of the `HttpRequestMessage` is used to acquire the `FormDataMultiPart` object.
- The`getField()` function and the `@FormDataParam` annotation are then used to extract the file from the form-data body. An HTTP response is then delivered when the file has been processed as necessary.

[image]

- To handle file uploads correctly, you need to modify the parameter type of the `run` method to accept `Multipart` data instead of `Optional<String>`.